# Очистка значений при смене select

Tags: javascript

Привет

Получилось сделать 4 скрытых инпута с выбранными значениями из селектов, но как исправить такую проблему: если я сначала вбрал одно значени, потом передумал и выбрад другое, то у меня все равно все добавляется в инпуты поочередн.
Как сделать чтобы либо они создавались уже при выбре 4 значения, или, что мне кажется лучше, очищались при смене значения - очищался именно тот, который был изменен.

```
$('#engine_id').change(function(){
    var engine_id = $('#engine_id :selected').val(); 
    if (engine_id !== '0') {
    var value1 = $('#marka_id :selected').text();
    var value2 = $('#model_id :selected').text();
    var value3 = $('#year_id :selected').text();
    var value = $('#engine_id :selected').text();
    $("#selectBoxtext").append("<input type='hidden' value='" + value1 + "'><input type='hidden' value='" + value2 + "'><input type='hidden' value='" + value3 + "'><input type='hidden' value='" + value + "'>");
    $('#selectBoxInfo').html('Выбран '+ value1+value2+value3+value).
    fadeIn(1000,function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(2000);
    }); 
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

куки,скрытое поле в форме,локальное хранилище.

Вариант похуже аякс+записывать данные при каждом выборе, сесии.

Comment: с помошю джеквери дайете значения свойству value скрытого поля       .$( ".class-input-hidden" ).val( text );       http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: уже помог)НА каком этапе возникает проблема?

Comment: да, я с помощью вашего кода сумел получить текст из option, в соседнем вопросе, посмотрите, не смог его вставить в input))

Comment: $('#selectBoxInfo').html('Выбран '+ value). замените на  $('#selectBoxInfo').html('Выбран '+ value1+valu2+value3+value). Де value1 = $("#id_selecta1:selected").text(); и так далее для value2

Comment: $( "#id" ).text( value ); -Вот вставка значения.